# Deserializing JSON response with list of NAMED objects

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am writing a Spring Boot app, which deals with REST API returning the following response schema:

```
{
  "id": 550,
  "results": {
    "AR": {
      "link": "https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/550-fight-club/watch?locale=AR",
      "flatrate": [
        {
          "display_priority": 1,
          "logo_path": "/68MNrwlkpF7WnmNPXLah69CR5cb.jpg",
          "provider_id": 119,
          "provider_name": "Amazon Prime Video"
        },
        {
          "display_priority": 7,
          "logo_path": "/rgbalNWbAuhWklHH5JAnF53Wjey.jpg",
          "provider_id": 339,
          "provider_name": "Movistar Play"
        }
      ],
      "rent": [
        {
          "display_priority": 2,
          "logo_path": "/q6tl6Ib6X5FT80RMlcDbexIo4St.jpg",
          "provider_id": 2,
          "provider_name": "Apple iTunes"
        },
        {
          "display_priority": 3,
          "logo_path": "/p3Z12gKq2qvJaUOMeKNU2mzKVI9.jpg",
          "provider_id": 3,
          "provider_name": "Google Play Movies"
        },
        {
          "display_priority": 8,
          "logo_path": "/mzu37NQphDvqN2BHKM0Rwq9Es3r.jpg",
          "provider_id": 167,
          "provider_name": "Claro video"
        }
      ],
      "buy": [
        {
          "display_priority": 2,
          "logo_path": "/q6tl6Ib6X5FT80RMlcDbexIo4St.jpg",
          "provider_id": 2,
          "provider_name": "Apple iTunes"
        },
        {
          "display_priority": 3,
          "logo_path": "/p3Z12gKq2qvJaUOMeKNU2mzKVI9.jpg",
          "provider_id": 3,
          "provider_name": "Google Play Movies"
        }
      ]
    },
    "AT": {
      "link": "https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/550-fight-club/watch?locale=AT",
      "rent": [
        {
          "display_priority": 2,
          "logo_path": "/q6tl6Ib6X5FT80RMlcDbexIo4St.jpg",
          "provider_id": 2,
          "provider_name": "Apple iTunes"
        },
        {
          "display_priority": 3,
          "logo_path": "/p3Z12gKq2qvJaUOMeKNU2mzKVI9.jpg",
          "provider_id": 3,
          "provider_name": "Google Play Movies"
        },
        {
          "display_priority": 7,
          "logo_path": "/vjKeS7Y9fNyqNtvp2ROCc71iu1u.jpg",
          "provider_id": 40,
          "provider_name": "Chili"
        },
        {
          "display_priority": 8,
          "logo_path": "/pZgeSWpfvD59x6sY6stT5c6uc2h.jpg",
          "provider_id": 130,
          "provider_name": "Sky Store"
        },
        {
          "display_priority": 10,
          "logo_path": "/sVBEF7q7LqjHAWSnKwDbzmr2EMY.jpg",
          "provider_id": 10,
          "provider_name": "Amazon Video"
        },
        {
          "display_priority": 14,
          "logo_path": "/mosNtwHNCqCmjk7n5odKgYYf2GI.jpg",
          "provider_id": 20,
          "provider_name": "maxdome Store"
        },
        {
          "display_priority": 18,
          "logo_path": "/wuViyDkbFp4r7VqI0efPW5hFfQj.jpg",
          "provider_id": 35,
          "provider_name": "Rakuten TV"
        },
        {
          "display_priority": 37,
          "logo_path": "/paq2o2dIfQnxcERsVoq7Ys8KYz8.jpg",
          "provider_id": 68,
          "provider_name": "Microsoft Store"
        }
      ],
      "buy": [
        {
          "display_priority": 2,
          "logo_path": "/q6tl6Ib6X5FT80RMlcDbexIo4St.jpg",
          "provider_id": 2,
          "provider_name": "Apple iTunes"
        },
        {
          "display_priority": 3,
          "logo_path": "/p3Z12gKq2qvJaUOMeKNU2mzKVI9.jpg",
          "provider_id": 3,
          "provider_name": "Google Play Movies"
        },
        {
          "display_priority": 7,
          "logo_path": "/vjKeS7Y9fNyqNtvp2ROCc71iu1u.jpg",
          "provider_id": 40,
          "provider_name": "Chili"
        },
        {
          "display_priority": 8,
          "logo_path": "/pZgeSWpfvD59x6sY6stT5c6uc2h.jpg",
          "provider_id": 130,
          "provider_name": "Sky Store"
        },
        {
          "display_priority": 10,
          "logo_path": "/sVBEF7q7LqjHAWSnKwDbzmr2EMY.jpg",
          "provider_id": 10,
          "provider_name": "Amazon Video"
        },
        {
          "display_priority": 14,
          "logo_path": "/mosNtwHNCqCmjk7n5odKgYYf2GI.jpg",
          "provider_id": 20,
          "provider_name": "maxdome Store"
        },
        {
          "display_priority": 18,
          "logo_path": "/wuViyDkbFp4r7VqI0efPW5hFfQj.jpg",
          "provider_id": 35,
          "provider_name": "Rakuten TV"
        },
        {
          "display_priority": 37,
          "logo_path": "/paq2o2dIfQnxcERsVoq7Ys8KYz8.jpg",
          "provider_id": 68,
          "provider_name": "Microsoft Store"
        }
      ]
    }
... like 50 more of the above ...
  }
}
```

While trying to write a DTO class to capture this response, I realized that since contents of "results" field act like a map, I have no idea how to write composition of the DTO objects for it. Normally I would write something like":

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ProviderSearchResultDto {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty("results")
    private List<CountryResultDto> results;
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CountryResultDto {

    @JsonProperty("link")
    private String link;

    @JsonProperty("flatrate")
    private List<ResultDto> result;

    @JsonProperty("rent")
    private List<ResultDto> rent;

    @JsonProperty("buy")
    private List<ResultDto> buy;
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ResultDto {

    @JsonProperty("display_priority")
    private int displayPriority;

    @JsonProperty("logo_path")
    private String logoPath;

    @JsonProperty("provider_id")
    private int providerId;

    @JsonProperty("provider_name")
    private int providerName;
}
```

But because in the response results acts like a collection of named entities, I have no idea what to do. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

you need to do  something like it:

```
public class Result {
    private AR ar;
    private At at;
}

public class AR {
    private List<Flatrate> flatRate;
    private List<Rent> rent;
    private List<Buy> buy;
}

public class AT {
    private List<Rent> rent;
    private List<Buy> buy;
}


public class Flatrate {
 private Integer displayPriority;
     ....
}

public class Rent{
     ....
}

public class Buy{
     ....
}
```

You Can use this https://www.freecodeformat.com/json2pojo.php site to convert the JSON to java object. it is more easy.

And this https://jsoneditoronline.org/ to see the JSON as tree format.